# Differences between NSTableView and NSCollectionView

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstableview, nscollectionview

I'm trying to decide which path to take for developing my Snow Leopard app. First, I should preface with the obvious differences:

`NSTableView` can have multiple columns of data for representing different parts of the same "element" of data (a row) where `NSCollectionView` can display a grid of data as well, but every row+column combo is its own element. For my purposes, assume I'm dealing with a single column.

1. As far as I can tell, `NSCollectionView` items are `NSView`s which all must be of the same dimensions. Also, unlike `NSTableView`, collectionview items are copied to the `NSCollectionView` instead of being provided as needed by a `dataSource` (I'm uncertain about this, please correct me if I'm wrong).
2. `NSTableView` uses `NSCell`s if you decide to customize the display of rows. As `NSCell` isn't an `NSResponder`, how does one handle events (if I wanted to add some sort of accessory to the cell, like how the Arrows in iTunes work (although, iTunes is Carbon). I've seen some `NSCell` subclasses in IB which appear to be equivalents of their `NSControl` brethren, but what if I want to have `MySweetView` objects in an `NSCell`?).
3. Both seem to work about the same with respects to Bindings, correct?
4. Finally, `NSCollectionView` appears to play nicely with animation of its elements (for re-arranging items, or filtering them for example). Can `NSTableView` do this with its rows?

Anything else I should consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The difference here is that in a table view, every row is one item, and the columns show different aspects (properties) of that item. In a collection view, every row-column intersection is one item.
2. I haven't done this, but try implementing `tableView:didClickTableColumn:` in your table view delegate. That method is new in 10.6. You would need to get `[NSApp currentEvent]`, and probably pass it to a method in the column's cell.
3. With a table view, you bind the column; you don't bind the view (not to provide content, anyway; you do bind the view for things like selection indexes). With a collection view, there are no columns (see #1), so you always bind the view.
4. No.

Comment: For number 1, I mentioned that in my preface. My concern is how the data is provided to the table vs CV. The CV's `NSCollectionViewItem` has a `representedObject` and also a `view` property, but does the CV ask a delegate for this info, or does the NSCVI act as a controller responsible for this or…? The documentation is seriously lacking for this class!

Comment: Looking at the class reference, it appears that you provide the collection view with your model objects in its `content`, and it will create CVIs for them from its prototype. Each model object is then the `representedObject` of a CVI.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, NSTableView is a very old part of the AppKit, and it's a bit crufty.

If you're new to the platform, I'd recommend getting your head around NSCollectionView first.