# View-based NSTableView vs NSCollectionView?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nscollectionview

I've understood the fly-weight approach of *cell-based* NSTableView and I think I understand the differences with NSCollectionView.<sup>[Differences between (cell-based) NSTableView and NSCollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1655489)</sup>

However, a bit less obvious is the differences between ***view-based*** NSTableView and NSCollectionView.

With NSCollectionView's flexibility in displaying its items (i.e. in a grid layout) which could emulate a tableView's list (a grid with maximum one column) and excluding personnal preferences, why would someone choose (View-based) NSTableView over NSCollectionView?

Comment: Because NSCollectionViews are one of the most fiddly things ever introduced in Cocoa? (That's only my opinion, of course.)

Comment: One pro argument for collections views over view-based tableviews for me is that insert/remove animations come out-of-the box and even work, when binding the collection view to a controller..

Answer (score 8):

**Update**: (Recycling of views is implemented since El Capitan)

`NSCollectionView` doesn't use view recycling. This means that a view will be created for every single collection view item, regardless of whether the view is on screen or not. This can wreck your performance with large data sets. A view based `NSTableView` uses view recycling and is very efficient, as it recycles a limited number of cells instead of creating new ones for every item. Not to mention that `NSCollectionView` is overall a poorly written and poorly documented class.

Comment: @ indragie: Confused: According to apple's doc here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSCollectionViewDataSource_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016649-CH1-SW6, views are being recycled in NSCollectionView, and they would, won't they?
Agree that `NSCollectionView` is poorly written though. :)

Comment: Just write a NSCollectionView for a OS X 10.10 compatible application. And  I would like to vote "NSCollectionView is overall a poorly written and poorly documented class". However, NSCollectionView of OSX10.11 may worth a try, it looks much better now.

Comment: Recycling of views is implemented since El Capitan